# Remote Service Vs. Local Service

Tags: android

Dear All,
I am a newbiew to Android. I had read a lot of articles about Android Service but I am not clearly understanding what defferent between Local Service and Remote Service (except for "Local Service run in the same process as the lunching activity; remote services run in their own process" - The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development - Mark L. Murphy ).

1. Please shows me what different between Local Service and Remote Service.
2. What's the advantage/disadvantage of using Local Service.
3. What's the advantage/disadvantage of using Remote Service.

Thanks & best regards
Dai Son

Answer (score 9):

Your description is exactly the difference between a local and remote service. There's nothing more to say. You will almost never want to use a remote service.

Comment: Thank you for providing a clear/concise answer! I've been trawling the internet for this as it's a significant design decision and I've seen tutorials on IPC/AIDL for android remote services but it isn't obvious why you'd adopt it.  With your answer I believe it now appears that these remote services are only useful if you plan on having multiple *applications* query a common background 'service' otherwise it's best to have the service as a local one and use threading for the time consuming tasks... please correct me if my understanding is incorrect as I'm about to start coding :)

Comment: @sradforth: `these remote services are only useful if you plan on having multiple applications query a common background 'service'` This is one of the use cases for a remote service. The other one is if your service needs to be started and stopped a lot or run continuously in the background (bad!), but your whole application takes a lot of ram, you can run the service remotely so your process memory maps are separated. I know the urbanairship push service uses this. But honestly I think it's very, very, very rarely the "best" design.

Comment: @Falmarri i have a Local service( extending `Service` class), and i bind my activities to the service. but when i execute any DB or HTTP operation i get an policy violation(Running a code which detects that violations), why it happens if i runnig that inside of my service. how do i place those operation on a non-UI Thread?.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between remote service and local service is: Local service runs in the same process and remote service runs in different process and may be in different application.

You can access a remote service which is running in the different application but you can't access a local service that is running in a different application.

Answer (score 0):

Local service means it runs in the same process probably in the same application. You can start a service using  the method `startService()` and you can stop the service by using the method `stopService()`. These two life cycle methods or Service And remote service are generally run in a different application. you can access them by writing AIDL Interfaces  and you can attach to a remote service by using binder.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can clarify the issue from my own experience:
LocalService:
To be created to serve local applications (activities) by providing background execution or performing some specific software functionality. Not accessible by other applications not in the same package except through intent.  Local service normally lives in the same process as the companion activity. But it can potentially have it's own process if needed.

Remote Service
This type of services normally design and implement software functionality to be used by other apps. Android system services (wifi/gps/usb/etc.)are the main examples in this category. If you need provide functionality to be used by other apps, you need to develop a remote service which implements remote binding, intent (through startCommand) or other IPC mechanism.

Remote or local it all depends on your need and application.

More readings:
[Android Official Document on service binding](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services).

Cheers,
David.