# Android Stop Service on Crash

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I am running a `Service` and am wondering in the rare case that my app crashes will it automatically kill my `Service` too? I don't want it continuing if this happens.

If not, is there a way to do this such as in the `onDestroy()` method?

Comment: What kind of service are you running?

Comment: @Prmths Background Location service. So it won't always be running, only if the users starts it. But I just want to be sure it stops in the event of a crash.

Comment: I can't find documentation for that class.  What's the class of the service you're using?

Comment: @Prmths It is my own class that extends `Service`. It uses `GooglePlayServices` to get Location Updates from the device.

Comment: I might suggest using a BoundService then rather than a subclass of Service.  The Android OS will kill a BoundService if nothing is bound to it.  Otherwise, as I understand it, the service won't be killed until the OS actually needs the system resources.

Comment: @Prmths's solution sounds the best. If for some reason you can't do that you could set a global exception handler which does nothing but stop the service and throw the original exception. I actually use it to log information to a custom log upon a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a bit of research, and I think I have a complete answer to your question.

Subclassing `Service` is fine, assuming you're not using a Remote Service (a `Service` in a different process.)  Assuming your `Service` is in the same process as your `Activity`, they'll both end together, in the event of a crash.  That being the case, my earlier suggestion to use `BoundService` wouldn't have actually produced a different result and was based on a flawed understanding of how Application Components work in Android processes.

Quoting from [Android bound service - should I manually reconnect in onServiceDisconnected or it tries reconnect automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699685/android-bound-service-should-i-manually-reconnect-in-onservicedisconnected-or):

> **Local Service:**
>
> Service is running in the same process as other components (i.e.
>   activity that bound to it) from the same application, when this single
>   application-scoped process has crashed or been killed, it is very
>   likely that all components in this process (include the activity that
>   bound to this service) are also destroyed.

Also, you can read [Remote Service Vs. Local Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710080/remote-service-vs-local-service).

Comment: How do I know if they are in the same process?

Comment: The only way I know of is to declare it in the Manifest.  `This is achieved by adding an android:process property within the <service> tag for the service in the manifest file. In order to launch a remote service it is also necessary to provide an intent filter for the service. To implement these changes, modify the AndroidManifest.xml file to add the required entries:` [Android Remote Bound Services – A Worked Example](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Remote_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example)