# Destroy Service on Android App Force Close/Crash

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

When an Android app is forced closed (System.exit(0)) or it crashes, the service associated with it, running in the background is not destroyed. In simple words, the onDestroy() method of service is not called. Because of this when the android app is restarted, the service starts up again ( its onCreate() is called right away). I want to avoid this.

So, the question is :

How Can I Destroy the background service in such a case as I don't have access to its onDestroy()?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057970/android-stop-service-on-crash

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending a regular plain `Service` class, then what you say won't happen. I think you are starting a `thread` for your service. If that's the case, then make sure you call `stopService` with the right `intent` to close the running `Service`. I am assuming your `Service` is a `started` service type and not `binding` type.

Comment: Yes, it is an started service and it is implementing a connectionEvent Listener. You told " If that's the case, then make sure you call stopService with the right intent to close the running Service", but my app is force closing/crashing. Where shall I call the "stopService" as onDestroy of the service is not called?

Comment: Fix the force closing issue first. If you alteast know which activity is causing force closing, then u can invoke stopService from that activitity's onPause() or onStop(). However, u should focus on fixing the force closing of ur app first, imho.

Comment: As per the force closing, there is no issue from the application side. Say someone uses an App killer to kill all the running app, in that case I want the service to be destroyed automatically. if my app is destroyed.

Comment: does that really matter? anyways mine has around 20+

Comment: I was going to suggest that you send out a broadcast in your activity's onDestroy() which the background service can receive and stopSelf() and exit. That would have been great if you had one or two activities. With 20+, it's not a very nice recommendation. Keep in mind that the system will eventually terminate your service when it needs resources for other apps. So, you don't really have to worry about that background service that will be running when your app gets killed by some external means. Just check if it's running when you re-start your app rather than trying to kill it voluntarily.

Comment: AFAIK, on app crash or force close,  activity's onDestroy() wont be called. It will be a mere system.exit(0) call.

Comment: BTW I have to have the service killed on an app crash, normal closure or forced closure, for security reason.

Comment: Wait, you are not calling System.exit(0), in your code, are you? If someone else calls that in their app, their app will close. Not yours. So, you are confusing me. If your app is force closing, i repeat, fix that first. If the System is force closing your app for need of resources, then onDestroy() or isFinishing() will be called. A 3rd party app won't be able to force close your app without System intervention since each app is sand boxed. I am not sure what you are worried about now.

Comment: And if the System kills the entire process that is hosting your app, then the Service thread will be terminated as well since it's part of that app process.

Comment: I am not calling system.exit().If you swipe out an appication from the list of recent apps, it is forced close. isnt it? if an app is closed that way the onDestroy()  is not called rather system.exit(0) is called. How can I kill my service in that case

Comment: I see. There is a way to get a list of currently running activities from the PacketManager class. I am not sure if you can register for listening to such events. Worst case, in your service, you could poll regularly to see if your activities are still running and manage the state of the service. But that's not a clean solution at all.

Comment: Just want to clarify one thing, is it that if an activity is destroyed, the background service is not destroyed automatically? what if I dont start the service but bind the service, will the problem persist?   I think the last solution cited by you is the only possibility..

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure that destruction of an activity does not mean the destruction of the entire TASK or the entire PROCESS and thus it is safe to assume that by destroying activity, does not mean other components such as service, etc that belong to that app process or TASK are also automatically destroyed. By killing that entire process, we can rest easy that all associated app components are destroyed too. If you create a bounded service, then that service will live as long as some component is bound to it. When no bindings are detected, it can be programmed to kill itself.

Comment: oh, I am sorry, I meant to write application and not activity :(

Comment: Yes. If the application is destroyed, all the components of it will get destroyed too :)